# How to split and recombine an unsigned long into signed shorts?

Tags: c

I need to store a large number, but due to limitations in an old game engine, I am restricted to working with `signed short` (I can, however, use as many of these as I want).

I need to split an `unsigned long` (0 to 4,294,967,295) into multiple `signed short` (-32,768 to 32,767). Then I need to recombine the multiple `signed short` into a new `unsigned long` later.

For example, take the number 4,000,000,000. This should be split into multiple `signed short` and then recombined into `unsigned long`.

Is this possible in C? Thanks.

Comment: What size are `unsigned long` and `signed short` on your system?  Can you give an example of some values you expect to get in/out of this?

Comment: I need to split `unsigned long` (0 to 4,294,967,295) into multiple `signed short` (-32,768 to 32,767) and back again.

Comment: Are you operating on the signed shorts, or just storing them somewhere and getting them later?

Comment: just storing and retrieving later.

Comment: `unsigned long` is not guaranteed to be 32 bits and `short` need not have 16 bits or even use 2's complement representation (especially on old machines). Use `stdint.h` types for fixed bit-width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your problem is finding a place to *store* these large values. There are options we haven't yet explored which don't involve splitting the values up and recombining them:

- Write them to a file, and read them back later. This might seem silly at first, but considering the bigger picture, if the values end up in a file later on then this might seem like the most attractive option.
- Declare your `unsigned long` to have *static storage duration* e.g. outside of any blocks of code A.K.A *globally* (I hate that term) or using the `static` keyword inside a block of code.

None of the other answers so far are strictly portable, not that it seems like it should matter to you. You seem to be describing a twos complement 16-bit `signed short` representation and a 32-bit `unsigned long` representation (you should put `assert`ions in place to ensure this is the case), which has implications that restrict the options for the implementation (that is, the C compiler, the OS, the CPU, etc)... so the portability issues associated with them are unlikely to occur. In case you're curious, however, I'll discuss those issues anyway.

The portability issues associated are that one type or the other might have padding bits causing the sizes to mismatch, and that there might be trap representations for `short`.

Changing the type but not the representation is by far much cleaner and easier to get right, though not portable; this includes the `union` hack, you could also avoid the `union` by casting an `unsigned long *` to a `short *`. These solutions are the cleanest solutions, which makes [Ken Clement's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35097898/1989425) my favourite so far, despite the non-portability.

Binary shifts (the `>>` and `<<` operators), and (the `&` operator), or (`|`) operators introduce additional portability issues when you use them on signed types; they're also bulky and clumsy leading to more code to debug and a higher chance that mistakes are made.

You need to consider that while `ULONG_MAX` is guaranteed to be at least 4,294,967,295, `SHORT_MIN` is not guaranteed by the C standard to be -32,768; it might be -32,767 (which is quite uncommon indeed, though still possible)... There might be a negative zero or trap representation in place of that -32,768 value.

This means you can't portably rely upon a pair of `signed short`s being able to represent all of the values of an `unsigned long`; even when the *sizes* match up you need another bit to account for the two missing values.

With this in mind, you could use a *third* `signed char`... The implementation-defined and undefined behaviours of the shift approaches could be avoided that way.

```
signed short x = (value      ) & 0xFFF,
             y = (value >> 12) & 0xFFF,
             z = (value >> 24) & 0xFFF;

value =  (unsigned long) x
      + ((unsigned long) y << 12)
      + ((unsigned long) z << 24);
```

Comment: Wow, all of the bemoaning I did about non-portability and I managed to introduce undefined behaviour in my example... This demonstrates just how easy it is to mess up shift operations.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to dbush's answer you can also use a union, e.g.:

```
union
{
    unsigned long longvalue;
    signed short shortvalues[2];
}
  value;
```

The array of two shorts overlays the single long value.

Comment: The question requires that the `short` type be `signed`... With that correction in mind, providing there are no padding bits or trap representations for these integer types this answer should be fine for this question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Seb.  I have modified the example appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (I used fixed size types to properly illustrate how it works):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t val1;
    int16_t val2a, val2b;
    uint32_t val3;

    val1 = 0x11223344;
    printf("val1=%08x\n", val1);

    // to short
    val2a = val1 >> 16;
    val2b = val1 & 0xFFFF;
    printf("val2a=%04x\n", val2a);
    printf("val2b=%04x\n", val2b);

    // to long
    val3 = (uint32_t)val2a << 16;
    val3 |= (uint32_t)val2b;
    printf("val3=%08x\n", val3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
val1=11223344
val2a=1122
val2b=3344
val3=11223344
```

Comment: By using the `x` format specifier without any length modifiers (not to be confused with field width specifiers, which you are using) tells `printf` to expect an `unsigned int`, however none of the arguments you provide are... This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `val2a = val1 >> 16;` is implementation defined behavior. val1 can be unrepresentable in val2a. If not a trap, the conversion can change the value.

Comment: Given the nature of what OP is doing (working with an old game engine), I think implementation defined behavior is acceptable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution (which assumes ulong is 32-bits, and sshort is 16-bits):

```
unsigned long L1, L2;
signed short S1, S2;

L1 = 0x12345678;    /* Initial ulong to store away into two sshort */
S1 = L1 & 0xFFFF;   /* Store component 1 */
S2 = L1 >> 16;      /* Store component 2*/
L2 = S1 | (S2<<16); /* Retrive ulong from two sshort */

/* Print results */
printf("Initial value: 0x%08lx\n",L1);
printf("Stored component 1: 0x%04hx\n",S1);
printf("Stored component 2: 0x%04hx\n",S2);
printf("Retrieved value: 0x%08lx\n",L2);
```

Comment: The number of people who use `printf` in answers demonstrating an incorrect understanding of the types corresponding to format specifiers astounds me. I wouldn't have the gall to answer a question as though I'm able to teach a subject I know so little about. The good thing is, you can learn if you're happy to exude the mental effort of concentrating on reading some decent resources, and decent resources are even easier to find than they are to concentrate on.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways to do it. One thing to consider is that `unsigned long` may not have the same size on different hardware/operating systems. You can use exact length types found in `stdint.h` to avoid ambiguity (e.g. `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, etc.). One implementation incorporating exact types (and cheezy hex values) would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void) {

    uint64_t a = 0xfacedeadbeefcafe, b = 0;
    uint16_t s[4] = {0};
    uint32_t i = 0, n = 0;

    printf ("\n a : 0x%16"PRIx64"\n\n", a);

    /* separate uint64_t into 4 uint16_t */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof a; i += 2, n++)
        printf (" s[%"PRIu32"] : 0x%04"PRIx16"\n", n, 
                (s[n] = (a >> (i * CHAR_BIT))));

    /* combine 4 uint16_t into uint64_t */
    for (n = i = 0; i < sizeof b; i += 2, n++)
        b |= (uint64_t)s[n] << i * CHAR_BIT;

    printf ("\n b : 0x%16"PRIx64"\n\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/uint64_16

 a : 0xfacedeadbeefcafe

 s[0] : 0xcafe
 s[1] : 0xbeef
 s[2] : 0xdead
 s[3] : 0xface

 b : 0xfacedeadbeefcafe
```

Comment: `%lx` and `%hx` don't necessarily correspond to arguments with type `uint32_t` and `uint16_t` respectively. You should probably consider using `%"PRIx32"` and `%"PRIx16"`, or casting the arguments, in order to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: Agreed and good catch. *Format-specifiers* updated, `inttypes.h` added.

Comment: Good. `%u` probably also should not be used to print `uint32_t`, either; you could use `%lu` and cast to a `long unsigned`, or use `%"PRIu32"`... `0x%04"PRIx32"` should definitely not be used to print a `uint16_t` value... and the `& 0xffff` in that expression is redundant. Did you mean to add a multiplier for `sizeof (uint16_t)` somewhere? For example, `s[n] = a >> (i * * sizeof s[n] * CHAR_BIT)` and `b |= (uint64_t)s[n] << i * sizeof s[n] * CHAR_BIT`

Comment: I also noted that the values you want to print are at most 16 hex digits, yet you're printing fields that are at least 8 hex digits long: `0x%8"PRIx64"` ... This could be intentional, I don't know, but it's probably more common to see `0x%16"PRIx64"`

Comment: No, the width wasn't intentional, just the fingers working faster than the brain. Just needed to knock the burrs off the final edge...